# How to ignore errors in code and continue working, but print error codes?

Tags: python

I have the code. I'm calling an error with `print(a)`. The error starts printing endlessly. I want the error code to be printed when an exception is thrown, but the code continues to be executed from the next line after the line that caused the error

```
while True:
   try:
      print(a)
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      continue
```

But the code starts again from the line with the error, need to ignore **line** and continue.

Output:

```
a is not found
a is not found
...
```

I'll describe what I want:

```
try:
    print(a) #Line of code 1
except:
    pass

try:
    print(b) #Line of code 2
except:
    pass
```

I want to check for error all lines of code like this.

But my code is 200+ lines, So many try-except constructions is silly to do, isn't it.

Comment: Why is your code wrapped in a `while`? Where do you want this code to go after the exception?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The thing is, ```a``` isn't defined, and thusly you keep on printing the error ```a is not found``` (or whatever the actual error message is).  Please include a minimal reproducible example and your expected output and your actual output.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `continue` for `break`.

```
while True:
   try:
      print(a)
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      break
```

You can read more **loop control statements** [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/break-continue-and-pass-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run in the same loop occurence, Without any continue block you can just add the rest of the code as it is outside the try and except block as follows :

```
while (condition):
  try:
    print(a)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
  # followed by the rest of code 
  print("contd")
```

or if you want to skip the current loop you can use `continue`.

And this is being repeated because you have set the loop condition to be true, so the loop never ends. To stop the loop you will need a `break` statement instead of continue.

Answer (score 0):

If your `200+ lines of code` really is 200 single line statements that you want to check, you could wrap each in a `lambda` and store them in a list and iterate over them checking for errors:

```py
all_functions = [lambda:print(a), lambda:print(b)]
for func in all_functions:
    try:
        func()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

After doing that for 200 lines, at least later, when you want to add another line, it can go on the end of the list in another lambda.